# Jquery Modal Selectable Data (Suggested Users)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, sql

I want to allow my users to enter a name but if it does not exist, then have the ability to select from a list of "suggested users". Is it possible to make the values in my jquery popup clickable or highlight one and select 'ok'. Currently I'm injecting my html from code behind but can change that if need be. TIA

Code Behind:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
               string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n $(document).ready(function gvPopup() {$('#popupdialog').dialog({width: 525, overflow: scroll, height: 220,  title: 'User Not Found !<br/> Please Enter a Suggested User Below'})});\n</script>";
```

I want the names below to be selectable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete widget in jQuery UI can be fairly easily customized to do what you describe.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

I recently had a very pleasant experience integrating it into an admin panel I was working on.  You have to set up an ajax script that spits out a json-formatted list of suggestions based on the current input and the widget pretty much takes care of the rest.  If you need it to work a bit differently than the typical case, the widget initialization call even allows you to provide your own handlers for selection etc.